# Why is this calling of a parent method not working? State not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to call a parent method from a component, to update the state, and it doesn't seem to be updating the state. The function is being called as the console log is running, but the state isn't updating.

I'm trying to run the `showFirstFive()` function, found on the `<CustomerTable />` component, from within its child component - `<CustomerEntry />` (passed as a prop).

The buttons at the top change the state fine, but the buttons in the table (in the child components) do not.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

[codepen here](https://codepen.io/ashconnolly/pen/VWvRgP/)

```
class CustomerEntry extends React.Component {
    modifyState(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("test");
        this.props.changeState;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.name}</td>
                <td>{this.props.email}</td>
                <td>{this.props.postcode}</td>
                <td>
                    {this.props.product}
                    <button onClick={this.modifyState.bind(this)}>Show first 5 items</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}

class CustomerTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        let customers = this.props.customers;
        this.state = {
            customers
        };
    }

    showFirstFive() {
        let customers = this.props.customers;
        customers = customers.slice(0, 5);
        this.setState({ customers });
    }
    showAll() {
        let customers = this.props.customers;
        this.setState({ customers });
    }

    render() {
        console.log("this.props.customers", this.props.customers);
        let customerList;

        let thisComp = this;

        if (this.props.customers) {
            customerList = this.state.customers.map(function(customerData) {
                return (
                    <CustomerEntry
                        key={customerData.key}
                        changeState={thisComp.showFirstFive.bind(this)}
                        index={customerData.key}
                        name={customerData.name}
                        email={customerData.email}
                        postcode={customerData.postcode}
                        product={customerData.product}
                    />
                );
            });
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.showFirstFive.bind(this)} >Show first 5 items</button>
                <button onClick={this.showAll.bind(this)} >Show all</button>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Postcode</th>
                            <th>Product</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {customerList}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            customers: [
                {
                    key: "86464",
                    name: "Mr John Smith",
                    email: "test@test.com",
                    postcode: "LN47AT",
                    product: "apples",
                },
                {
                    key: "787862",
                    name: "Miss Sarah Jackson",
                    email: "sarah@hello.com",
                    postcode: "DN54LQ",
                    product: "apples",
                },
                {
                    key: "4454564",
                    name: "Dr Hugh James",
                    email: "hugh@test.com",
                    postcode: "S102AT",
                    product: "bananans",
                },              {
                    key: "11123134",
                    name: "Mr John Smith",
                    email: "test@test.com",
                    postcode: "LN47AT",
                    product: "apples",
                },
                {
                    key: "68868",
                    name: "Miss Sarah Jackson",
                    email: "sarah@hello.com",
                    postcode: "DN54LQ",
                    product: "apples",
                },
                {
                    key: "6876871",
                    name: "Dr Hugh James",
                    email: "hugh@test.com",
                    postcode: "S102AT",
                    product: "bananans",
                },
                                {
                    key: "17117",
                    name: "Mr John Smith",
                    email: "test@test.com",
                    postcode: "LN47AT",
                    product: "apples",
                },
                {
                    key: "17171716",
                    name: "Miss Sarah Jackson",
                    email: "sarah@hello.com",
                    postcode: "DN54LQ",
                    product: "apples",
                },
                {
                    key: "151571",
                    name: "Dr Hugh James",
                    email: "hugh@test.com",
                    postcode: "S102AT",
                    product: "bananans",
                },

            ]
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <CustomerTable customers={this.state.customers} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call that method, missed `()`:

```
modifyState(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("test");
    this.props.changeState();    //here
}
```

**Suggestion:**

**1.** Instead of binding the methods by:

```
onClick = {this.showFirstFive.bind(this)}
```

Define it in the constructor:

```
this.showFirstFive = this.showFirstFive.bind(this);
```

Then use it like this: `onClick = {this.showFirstFive}`

**2.** Storing the reference of `this` keyword in a separate variable is not required, you are use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) like this:

```
customerList = this.state.customers.map((customerData) => {
      //now you can access this
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the super quick reply mate! That sorted it perfectly! Thanks for the arrow function help too! Really appreciate it! Cheers! 

Comment: Any advice on react state filtering? Need to setup a search + column sorting + pagination. I guess its just JS object modification and updating the state. any links / advice is v welcome! 

Comment: i will suggest you to use `react-bbotstrap-table`, by default it provides **search, sorting, pagination** and many other cool features and best thing is very easy to use. Check the docs and example: http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/index.html

Comment: That looks ace! I found https://github.com/glittershark/reactable, but bootstrap-table looks great! Thanks so much mate! 